# ShowDialog() while another form is visible through ShowDialog() as well, closes both?

Tags: c#, winforms, showdialog

I have the following situation:

1. `ParentForm` which opens `WelcomeForm` with `ShowDialog`.
2. `WelcomeForm` contains a Button which opens `NewProjectForm` with `ShowDialog`
3. When the user hits `OK` on `NewProjectForm`, a new project is created and both forms are closed (good behaviour)
4. When the user hits `CANCEL` on `NewProjectForm`, both forms are closed (understandable behaviour, but not desireable).

I suspect this somehow has something to do with `DialogResult` (which is actually `DialogResult.None` on `CANCEL` *and* `NewProjectForm`)

How can I get the above situation without both forms closing?

**Edit**
Code used to open `NewProjectForm`:

```
ProjectNew projectNew = new ProjectNew();
projectNew.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
projectNew.ShowDialog(this);
```

Code used to open `WelcomeForm`:

```
Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
welcome.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
welcome.ShowDialog(this);
```

*Note: `NewProjectForm` is **not** opened by `Welcome` but by `ParentForm`*

**Edit 2**
Strange stuff; I created a new project with the same code/situation, which doesn't reproduce this behaviour...

Comment: Can you share the code that displays `NewProjectForm`?

Comment: It seems odd that the WelcomeForm should close when the NewProjectForm is closed, given the code sample. Is this done in the button click events.

Comment: You need to paste more code - ideally the whole classes for both forms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed a couple of buttons, added a new one: solved.
So I think it should have been a DialogResult somehow, weird stuff.

Comment: I suspect the buttons had their DialogResult properties set to something other than None.  That might explain why this fixed the problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I got bitten by this because I had copy/pasted some buttons from another form, not realizing that one of the **buttons** had it's DialogResult property set to **DialogResult.Cancel**.

When clicked, this was setting the containing form's DialogResult, causing it to close.

Resetting it to **DialogResult.None** fixed the problem.

So, check the DialogResult properties on all your modal dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

This has been a long-standing issue that I have run up against a few times. [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/cumgranosalis/archive/2005/10/03/ShowDialog-in-ShowDialog.aspx) post has more discussion on it, as well as a workaround.

It has apparently been fixed in .Net 3.5 SP1 (I can no longer reproduce it after installing SP1), although I haven't seen any official word on that it was definitely fixed.

Comment: I've seen that post and tried the workaround by setting DialogResult = DialogResult.None, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the behavior (tested both on .NET 3.5 SP1 and .NET 4 Beta 2)